# longtable environment: first column takes a huge amount of space

Tags: spacing, longtable

first post hhere so please be gentle :) i´m writing my PhD thesis, came up with a problem in one of my longtables. basically the first column takes a lot of unused space, pushing the last two columns outside of the page margins. I can't figure out what's wrong with my code. Down below you can see my MWE. any suggestions?

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{seqsplit}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{ae,aecompl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{epsf}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{appendix}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage{placeins}
\setlength{\textwidth}{150mm}
\setlength{\textheight}{230mm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{3mm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{3mm}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{longtable}{c c c c c c c}
        \caption{Calculated and measured thin film parameters.}\\
        \hline
Sub-Film & $T_C$(K)&$ \Delta T_C$ (K)&$J_C (MA/cm^2)$& RRR &  $\Delta$ (meV) & $L_k$ ($pH/\square$)\\
\hline
\endfirsthead
{\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\
\hline
Sub-Film &   $T_C$ (K)    & $ \Delta T_C$ (K)   & $J_C (MA/cm^2)$    & RRR &  $\Delta$ (meV) & $L_k$ ($pH/\square$)\\
\hline
\endhead
\hline
\endfoot
\hline
\endlastfoot
Si-NbN15-1 & 11.2 & 0.5 & 3.25 & 0.88 & 1.71  & 28.5 \\

Si-NbN15-2 & 11   & 0.47& 3.21 & 0.88 & 1.67  & 27.4 \\

Sa-NbN15   & 13.4 & 0.18& 9.3  & 1.07 & 2.03  & 7.28 \\

Sa-NbN30   & 13.9 & 0.09& n.a.  & 1.09 & 2.11  & 3.33 \\

Sa-NbN5    & 12.48 &  0.27  & 2.28 & 0.96 & 1.89  & 30.33\\

SaAu-NbN13.3&13.04 &  0.3   & 6.65 & 1.11 & 1.98  & 7.57 \\

SaNb-NbN13.3&13.05 &  0.27  & 6.78 & 1.08 & 1.98  & 8.34 \\

SaAu-NbN25.5&13.53 &  0.18  & n.a.   & 1.12 & 2.05  & 3.76 \\

SaNb-NbN25.5&13.295&  0.2   & n.a.   & 1.1  & 2.02  & 3.96 \\

Di-NbN15    & 9.05 &  1.24  & 0.567 & 0.91 & 1.44  & 22.77\\

Di-Nb15     & 6.85 & 0.1    & n.a.   & 1.79 & 1.04  & 3.25 \\

Di-Nb30     &7.27  & 0.08   & n.a.   & 2.04 & 1.1   & 1.57
        \label{lk}
    \end{longtable}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you have put `{\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}}` into the first column

Comment: you could/should have removed every package not used in the example, but as they are there, please remove ae,aecomp,epsf, epsfig packages from your document, no documents written in the last 30 years should have those loaded

Comment: suggestion duly noted and implemented. thanks!

Comment: Why not just use `\caption[]{ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\ ` instead of `{\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\ `?

Comment: first time i use the longtable environment, got the syntax from an example online but thanks, will try to implement everything. feel very dumb now since the solution was trivial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue for the overly wide first column is the use of `{\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\`  which places the whole text inside of the first column. Either use a `\multicolumn` as in `\multicolumn{7}{c}{\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\`  or a `\caption` command as in `\caption{ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\` .

The following MWE contains some more suggestions on how you could improve your table. For consistent units and improved alignment of numbers inside of their columns, I used `siunitx`. For horizontal lines with improved spacing around them, I used the `booktabs` package. To save some space and in order to make sure the table fits into the available textwidth, I alsi introduced linebreaks in the column headers with the help of the `\thead` command from `makecell`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize}
\setlength{\textwidth}{150mm}
\setlength{\textheight}{230mm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{3mm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{3mm}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{l 
                  S[table-format=2.3] 
                  S[table-format=2.2]
                  S[table-format=2.3] 
                  *{2}{S[table-format=1.2]} 
                  S[table-format=2.2]}
\caption{Calculated and measured thin film parameters.}\label{lk}\\
\toprule
Sub-Film &   {\thead{$T_C$\\ (\si{\K})}}    & {\thead{$\Delta T_C$\\ (\si{\K})}}   & {\thead{$J_C$\\ (\si{MA\per\cm\squared})}}    & {\thead{RRR}} &  {\thead{$\Delta$\\ (\si{\milli\electronvolt})}} & {\thead{$L_k$\\ ($pH/\square$)}}\\
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\caption{ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\
\toprule
Sub-Film &   {\thead{$T_C$\\ (\si{\K})}}    & {\thead{$\Delta T_C$\\ (\si{\K})}}   & {\thead{$J_C$\\ (\si{MA\per\cm\squared})}}    & {\thead{RRR}} &  {\thead{$\Delta$\\ (\si{\milli\electronvolt})}} & {\thead{$L_k$\\ ($pH/\square$)}}\\
\midrule
\endhead
\bottomrule
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot
Si-NbN15-1 & 11.2 & 0.5 & 3.25 & 0.88 & 1.71  & 28.5 \\

Si-NbN15-2 & 11   & 0.47& 3.21 & 0.88 & 1.67  & 27.4 \\

Sa-NbN15   & 13.4 & 0.18& 9.3  & 1.07 & 2.03  & 7.28 \\

Sa-NbN30   & 13.9 & 0.09& {n.a.}  & 1.09 & 2.11  & 3.33 \\

Sa-NbN5    & 12.48 &  0.27  & 2.28 & 0.96 & 1.89  & 30.33\\

SaAu-NbN13.3&13.04 &  0.3   & 6.65 & 1.11 & 1.98  & 7.57 \\

SaNb-NbN13.3&13.05 &  0.27  & 6.78 & 1.08 & 1.98  & 8.34 \\

SaAu-NbN25.5&13.53 &  0.18  & {n.a.}   & 1.12 & 2.05  & 3.76 \\

SaNb-NbN25.5&13.295&  0.2   & {n.a.}   & 1.1  & 2.02  & 3.96 \\

Di-NbN15    & 9.05 &  1.24  & 0.567 & 0.91 & 1.44  & 22.77\\

Di-Nb15     & 6.85 & 0.1    & {n.a.}   & 1.79 & 1.04  & 3.25 \\

Di-Nb30     &7.27  & 0.08   & {n.a.}   & 2.04 & 1.1   & 1.57\\
        
    \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you very much, leandris! looks defo better, will use your code in my main tex and also will try to clean it from useless packages to streamline it. much appreciated! take care.

Comment: @Brucci0: If you like my answer and it was helpful, please consider [upvoting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and/or marking it as the [accepted answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓).

Comment: yeah sure no problem! i'm new to SE and still tryiing to wrap my head around the mechanics of the whole site ;)